# Date Validation using MVC Validation Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have written a date validation attribute -

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    Match regExMatch = Regex.Match(value.ToString().Trim(), @"(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)");

    if (regExMatch.Success)
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }   
}
```

My cshtml is -

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.History.TheDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.History.TheDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

My Model is -

```
[DateValidator(ErrorMessage = "test")]
[Display(Name = "2020/21 Date?"), DateRangeTheDateAttibute(ErrorMessage = "Date must be after 28/09/2020"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? TheDate { get; set; }
```

If a user enters in an Invalid date such as 31/02/2021 the object value is null.  I want to be able to accept null dates but flag up invalid dates.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Doesnt the built in validation behave this way? I dont think you need to write your own.

Comment: You can type in an invalid date into the datepicker field and when you submit it just saves null to the model.

Comment: Just confirmed, with no attribute I get "The field TestDate must be a date." when trying to submit your date: "31/02/2021"

Comment: I took off my DateValidator attribute off and it let me type in 31/02/2021.  Are you talking about taking all attributes off?>

Comment: I'm not using any attributes: `public DateTime? TestDate { get; set; }`

Comment: It also lets me submit blank value for null.

Comment: Wait... I'm also using client side validation (jquery validation). That is catching it for me. This is more than likely the difference. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have alook at that link.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enter invalid date in `datetime?` object, even you accept invalid date values at validation time. Because of `datetime` type Limitations and rules.